# Gridview builder inside list view builder preloads all gridview items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a GridView builder inside a ListView builder as shown below (complete app example):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int sectionIndex) {
          return GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 111 / 221,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            ),
            itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              print("Loading item $sectionIndex $index");
              return Text("Item $index");
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I get in logs is `Loading item $sectionIndex $index` for ALL indexes inside the section I'm currently on.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJwuq.png)
However, if I use GridView alone without being a child in ListView, it loads around 10 items only and when I scroll down it loads more (which is the expected behavior)

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong in having grid view inside list view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the behavior of **ListView.builde**r because **ListView.builder** is flex widget that can `expand` it's `length` in the `scroll direction` according to it's `children` and same rule is followed by **GridView.builder**. So when you call **GridView.builder** iniside **ListView.builder**, **GridView.builder** has no limitation of height so it loads all their child according to available space.

After calling two **GridView.builders ListView.builder** has reached it's `max length` without any scroll so `3rd` **GridView.builder** will not build at the same time when previous two was `build`.

And to get limited result from **GridView.builder** just `wrap` that to `SizedBox` with a specific `height`.

I hope I was able to explain you.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. But what if I want to achieve such behavior? I have a list of sections, each section contains list of items in a grid layout. That's why I'm using a grid view to display the items inside the section which is inside the list view alongside other sections. I used to do it natively in iOS using TableView each cell contained CollectionView, how can I achieve this in flutter?

Comment: The only solution that I have described in my answer to wrap your Gridview into Sizedbox with specific height.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. just add `shrinkWrap` and `physics` inside `ListView.builder()`

```
 shrinkWrap: true,
 physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Full code:

```
         ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int sectionIndex) {
              return GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                gridDelegate:
                    const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 111 / 221,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                ),
                itemCount: 50,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print("Loading item $sectionIndex $index");
                  return Text("Item $index");
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

Result screen-> [image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help, physics should be scrollable because the list view will scroll. ShrinkWrap didn't help

Comment: what do you exact want?

Comment: I want a scrollable list view because it'll have multiple sections, each section is a grid view with multiple items. I don't want the grid view to preload all its items because it affects the performance of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  late List<Widget> widgets = [_gridView(), _gridView()];
  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() {
          setState(() {
            widgets.add(_gridView());
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          itemCount: widgets.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (widgets.length - 1 == index) {
              return Center(child: Text("Load more"));
            }
            return widgets[index];
          },
        ));
  }

  Widget _gridView() {
    return GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: 111 / 221,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("Item $index");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pagination and it doesn't solve the issue. The gridview still preloads all items inside it.

Comment: @MahmoudTarek Check it now